# Deconstructing struct wrapped in a Mutex

Tags: rust

I wrote this example (not working):

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::ops::Deref;

pub struct DBAndCFs {
    db: i32,
    cfs: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let x: Mutex<Option<DBAndCFs>> = Mutex::new(Some(DBAndCFs{ db: 0, cfs: Vec::new() } ));
    let DBAndCFs { ref db, ref cfs } = x.lock().unwrap().deref();
}
```

I have been following the docs but I am still unable to assign the `db`and `cfs`fields to the variables on the left.

Comment: Usually we don't use `.deref()` but `&*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Mutex::lock()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) returns `Result<MutexGuard, PoisonError>`. The first `.unwrap()` unwraps this `Result`. You need another `.unwrap()` to unwrap the `Option`, and also `.as_ref()` to not move out of it:

```rust
let DBAndCFs { ref db, ref cfs } = x.lock().unwrap().as_ref().unwrap();
```

You also don't need the `ref` because of match ergonomics (see [What does pattern-matching a non-reference against a reference do in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641939/what-does-pattern-matching-a-non-reference-against-a-reference-do-in-rust)):

```rust
let DBAndCFs { db, cfs } = x.lock().unwrap().as_ref().unwrap();
```

Comment: as_ref();
^^^^^^ method not found in `DBAndCFs `

Comment: see above please. as_ref() is not avail in the unwrap type, which seems strange as it's not even a DBAndCFs at this point in the chain.

Comment: @JohnDifool [It does work on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e836bfd6a323503e9570760ec96deb0). So if it does not work with your code then your MRE is wrong. The probable reason is that you don't use `std::sync::Mutex` but another mutex (e.g. `parking_lot::Mutex` or `tokio::sync::Mutex`). These do not implement [Lock Poisoning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#poisoning) and thus their `lock()` method does not return a `Result` but immediately a guard, so the first `.unwrap()` is redundant.

Comment: You are right. I had to switch to parking_lot::Mutex because the rest of the lib is using it. I am still having an issue with as_ref() as I think the vec is not a vector of int32 but a vec of structs that don't have AsRef trait. I'll update the OP with an EDIT.

Comment: Actually, I opted to close this question because the `self.db.lock().as_ref().unwrap()` did the work with `parking_lot::Mutex`. I have another issue with creating a temporary which is freed while still in use, but i decided to post another question about it.